# Why this corollary force ${\rm Aut}(H)=1$, where $H$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

This is on Dummit and Foote P134.

If $H\cong\Bbb Z_2$, then since $H$ has unique elements of orders $1$ and $2$, corollary 14 forces ${\rm Aut}(H)=1$.

Corollary 14: If $K$ is any subgroup of group $G$ and $g\in G$, then $K\cong gKg^{-1}$. Conjugate elements and conjugate subgroups have the same order.

I can see since ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z_2)$ has only trivial automorphism, and $H\cong\Bbb Z_2$, so ${\rm Aut}(H)=1$.

But I can not see how corollary 14 showed that, since to me, corollary 14 only showed that the conjugation is trivial, and didn't show that ${\rm Aut}(H)$ is trivial.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If the automorphism group is not trivial, then the element of order 2 must be mapped to another element of order 2 by corollary 14.

Comment: @Greg That corollary would only apply to inner automorphisms, and abelian groups have none.

Comment: That corollary does not apply, since it would only tell you about inner automorphisms. Instead, the identity is mapped to the identity, so injectivity forces the nontrivial element to be mapped to itself, showing any automorphism is just the identity map.

Comment: Every automorphism becomes an inner automorphism in the holomorph $H\rtimes\mathrm{Aut}(H)$, but this is overkill in this tiny case.

Comment: What edition are you supposed to be using? I'm looking at the 2nd edition, and page 134 contains nothing of the sort. Please provide complete and useful references, not vague ones.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I used third edition.

Comment: Put relevant information in the post, not buried in comments. Do not rely on pictures to convey information not otherwise present in your post.